# how to allow AWS Textract access to a protected S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-textract

I have bucket policy which allows access only from a VPC:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "aksdhjfaksdhf",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Access-only-from-a-specific-VPC",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::zzzz",
        "arn:aws:s3:::zzzz/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-xxxx"
        }
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to allow traffic coming from AWS Textract to this bucket as well. I've tried various methods but because of the absolute precedence of 'explicit deny' (which I require), I cannot make it work.

Is there a different policy formulation or a different method altogether to restrict the access to this S3 Bucket to traffic from the VPC AND from Textract service exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible.

In general, it's a good idea to avoid `Deny` policies since they override any `Allow` policy. They can be notoriously hard to configure correctly.

One option would be to remove the `Deny` and be very careful in who is granted `Allow` access to the bucket.

However, if this is too hard (eg Admins are given access to *all* buckets by default), then a common practice is to **move sensitive data to an S3 bucket in a different AWS Account** and only grant cross-account access to specific users.